# Recursively replace with RegEx w/ grep & sed while maintaining capture groups?

Tags: sed, files, grep, regular-expression, recursive

What a long title. Essentially, what I have is a collection of files that need to be searched recursively with a regex, and replaced.

What I have so far works without capture groups, however it does nothing when using them. I am currently using a command that I found on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26602094/10638556):

```
grep -rlP "/\* *(\d+) *\*/ (.*)" . | xargs sed -i "s/\/\* *(\d+) *\*\/ (.*)/$2 \/\/ JD $1/g"
```

This regex is very confusing because it contains a lot of escaped asterisks and slashes, but essentially it takes in the string (for example)

```
/*  73 */   private static int last = -1000;
```

and replacing it with

```
private static int last = -1000; // JD 73
```

However, as I said earlier, it simply does not work, and the files are unchanged.

It works fine with an alternate regex that does not utilize capture groups

```
grep -rl "/\* *\*/ " . | xargs sed -i "s/\/\* *\*\/ //g"
```

but as soon as I try to introduce capture groups, it just silently fails.

I can tell it's searching through the files, as I can hear the drive spin up for a moment like with the successful one, but in the end the files remain unchanged.

Could it be possible to modify the command such that it works, or must I do it in a completely different way? Also, ideally the solution wouldn't require a bash loop. Thanks.

Comment: `(` and `)` are literal in sed basic regular expressions - see [Why does my regular expression work in X but not in Y?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119905/why-does-my-regular-expression-work-in-x-but-not-in-y)

Comment: So you are saying they must be escaped?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Replace `-P` with `-E` in `grep` and use `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]+` instead of `(\d+)` since you don't use any other Perl-compatible things and you don't need the parentheses
- Remove `(.*)` from `grep`, this is redundant
- Add `-E` to `sed` or you have to escape your capturing groups `(...)` and the `+`
- Sed doesn't understand `\d+`, replace it with `[[:digit:]]` or `[0-9]+`
- Replace the backreferences `$1` with `\1` and `$2` with `\2`
- I think you can safely remove the `g`, JD only creates one comment at the beginning of the line.

```
grep -Erl '/\* *[[:digit:]]+ *\*/' . |
  xargs sed -Ei 's/\/\* *([[:digit:]]+) *\*\/ (.*)/\2 \/\/ JD \1/'
```

Comment: Ah, so you recognized it's from JD! I was wondering if anybody would. I was under the impression the `g` would be required in order for it to work multiple times on the same file. And replacing the `$` with `\` creates an error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 42: invalid reference \2 on `s' command's RHS`. (Command is `grep -rlE "/\* *[0-9]+ *\*/ .*" . | xargs sed -iE "s/\/\* *([0-9]+) *\*\/ (.*)/\2 \/\/ JD \1/"`)

Comment: Yes, guilty, Java guy. No, you need the `g` to apply the substitution more than once on each line. Your command looks okay, you even have removed the parenthesis I forgot. Just replace `-iE` with `-Ei`. This confuses `sed`, it thinks `E` is the backup suffix and the expression is run without the `-E` option. You may also remove the ```.*``` in `grep`.

Comment: Hmm. That almost worked. My command is now `grep -rlE "/\* *[0-9]+ *\*/ " . | xargs sed -Ei "s/\/\* *([0-9]+) *\*\/ (.*)/\2 \/\/ JD \1/" `. However, it now puts `\1` on a newline from `\2` and I am not sure why. I assume that it is picking up the newline at the end, and inserting it in `\2`. However, I don't know how to get rid of this. I tried putting a `\n` at the end of the capture group (`grep -rlE "/\* *[0-9]+ *\*/ .*\n" . | xargs sed -Ei "s/\/\* *([0-9]+) *\*\/ (.*)\n/\2 \/\/ JD \1/"`, however that made it never activate, I assume the newline isn't given to sed. Maybe I could trim it?

Comment: Check if your files have DOS CRLF line endings (`cat -A file` on a modified file). This would "move" the modified comment to the the beginning of each line when printed with `cat` without `-A`.

Comment: (Deleted comment was irrelevant) - Yes. It is DOS CRLF, as it displays `^M$` at the end of the line. After realizing this, I simply added a `\r` after the capture group so as not to capture it, and that solved it! Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

In `sed`, captured groups are referenced with `\1`,`\2`, etc. instead of `$1`, `$2`, etc. See [Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Back_002dreferences-and-Subexpressions.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use only `sed`, like this example

```
echo "/*  73 */   private static int last = -1000;" | 
    sed 's#^/\*[[:blank:]]*\([0-9]*\)[[:blank:]]*\*/[[:blank:]]*\(.*\)$#\2 // JD \1#g'
private static int last = -1000; // JD 73
```